# Xamarin.Android Fragments Preserve Data but Overlapping After Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin, fragment

First of all, I have searched and found a lot of similar issues like what I'm experiencing, however, I had tried the solutions posted there and none have worked for me.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I switch from tab to tab and then rotate the device, there's a Fragment overlapping the selected one.

Here is the code I'm using. Let me know if there's more information needed.

Activity:

```
public class SupervisionDetailsActivity : Activity, ActionBar.ITabListener
{
    private enum TabType { Summary, Data1, Data2 }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SupervisionDetails);

        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        AddTab("Summary", TabType.Summary);
        AddTab("External", TabType.Data1);
        AddTab("Internal", TabType.Data2);
    }

    private void AddTab(string label, TabType type)
    {
        var tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetTag(type.ToString());
        tab.SetText(label);

        tab.SetTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }

    public void OnTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        var f = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tab.Tag.ToString());

        switch (tab.Position)
        {
            case 0:
                if (f != null)
                    ft.Show(f);
                else
                    ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsSummary(), TabType.Summary.ToString());
                break;
            case 1:
                if (f != null)
                    ft.Show(f);
                else
                    ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsData1(), TabType.Data1.ToString());
                break;
            case 2:
                if (f != null)
                    ft.Show(f);
                else
                    ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsData2(), TabType.Data2.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void OnTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {

    }

    public void OnTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        var f = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tab.Tag.ToString());
        ft.Hide(f);
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save selected tab
        outState.PutInt("tab", ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex);
    }

    protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore selected tab
        int saved = savedInstanceState.GetInt("tab", 0);
        if (saved != ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex)
            ActionBar.SetSelectedNavigationItem(saved);
    }
}
```

If I replace those lines:

```
ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsSummary(), TabType.Summary.ToString());
ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsData1(), TabType.Data1.ToString());
ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsData2(), TabType.Data2.ToString());
```

With those:

```
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsSummary(), TabType.Summary.ToString());
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsData1(), TabType.Data1.ToString());
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentSupervisionDetailsData2(), TabType.Data2.ToString());
```

The overlapping problem is gone but the data/information from the fragments are lost which is not what I want.

Now, let me explain why the data is important to keep.

The first time the Fragments are created, there's no information (unless pulled from the database).

The information is collected from 3 places (the 3 tabs), the Summary which contains a little but important information like the Manager, Supervisor, etc and which does some calculations based on the data on the next tabs. The External and Internal contains a lot of controls like EditTexts, RadioButtons, etc.

The information or data is not saved immediately and sometimes is not even saved (not needed to). This is because there are a lot of times that the user captures some data in tab 1 and then switches to tab 3, then to tab 2, and again to tab 1, and so on. And as I said, occasionally is only for getting some quick information calculated in the tab 1 (Summary) which is not useful for saving.

That's the reason the data don't need to be destroyed when changing tabs, hence the use of Hide and Show.

I know I can temporarily store the information using a variety of methods, but it is really a lot of information (like around 180 variables in tab 3 for giving an example). The most practical and easy way I have come is to avoid re-creating the Fragments.

Anyway, with this information in mind, could I get some advice on how I can avoid the overlapping and at the same time retain the information stored in those Fragments when switching through them?

I really appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking over and over again, I ended implementing a combination of ActionBar.Tab with ViewPager like shown here:

[HelloSwipeViewWithTabs](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/ActionBarViewPager/)

And setting the OffscreenPageLimit to a value of 2 for maintaining the data of the 3 tabs.

The result is very similar to what I had just with a nice swipe feature for easily navigating through the Fragments.